# Pass string (csv) to stored procedure and search column (csv) contains

Tags: mysql, csv, stored-procedures, find-in-set

I started working in an existing system and facing the below issue

in my table having a field "tags" related to a site article were stored like this: 
row1 "dotnet,oracle,training,tutorials,oops" 
row2 "java,oracle,training,tutorials,oops" 
row3 "java,training,oops"
row4 "java,dotnet,oracle,training,tutorials,oops"

I wish to search for a tag "java tutorials" using stored procedure, I would like to get the out put as
row2
row3

For search "java oops training"
result
row2
row3
row4

It's a existing DB and Stored procedure, I can't redesign the database (like splitting the tags into new table) but I could update the stored procedure.

Looking for an efficient option, since my table contains huge records

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wish to search for A tag "java tutorials" - judging by your output looks more like 2 tags separated by a space

Comment: @P.Salmon , I want the output which records containing "java" and "tutorials"